# Unable to open ListPreferences from within an Activity Group

Tags: android, android-layout, android-preferences

I have got a list preferences as shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <ListPreference android:key="userType"
                    android:title="User Type"
                    android:summary="This preference allows to select an item in a array"
                    android:defaultValue="Admin"
                    android:entries="@array/array_preference_userType"
                    android:entryValues="@array/array_preference_userTypeValues" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

And the Prefs class is

```
public class PreferencesActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preference_user_settings);
 }
}
```

And the above class is added to activity group while opening.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getParent(), PreferencesActivity.class);
ParentActivity parentActivity = (ParentActivity)getParent();
parentActivity.startChildActivity("PreferencesActivity", intent);
```

ParentActivity class is:

```
public class ParentActivity extends ActivityGroup {
private ArrayList<String> mIdList;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);       
    if (mIdList == null) mIdList = new ArrayList<String>();
}

 public void startChildActivity(String Id, Intent intent) {     
     Window window = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(Id,intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
      if (window != null) {
          Log.i("ParentActivity", "activity started: " + Id);
          mIdList.add(Id);
          setContentView(window.getDecorView()); 
      }    
  }
   }
}
```

But when I click on the list preference, it crashes with the error

```
E/AndroidRuntime(581): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@44f862a8 is not valid; is your activity running?
```

I could possibly think of a solution of adding parent context which is what I am doing while creating the intent.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try to call it straight? For example: Intent newInt = new Intent(this,PreferencesActivity.class); ?

Comment: yes, it failed! You can't use this in child activities. In fact, pass parent context.

Comment: Can you add some more of the code around the intent? I think it's not quite clear where the error is.

Comment: Add the preferences layout to layout and reference it from that!

Comment: @dmon updated with Parent class

Comment: @all solved the problem. It happened to be a limitation with TabHost. As a result, parent context has to be forced into PreferencesActivity class. Anyway, that did the trick! Thanks all for the inputs!